# nodejs docker localhost website is not working

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I want to run my nodejs app with docker but it seems not to be working

I have created my dockerfile

built and image

and created a container from the image

I tried accessing it through web browser but it is not working

Nodejs Code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ name: "John Stone", email: "stone@gmail.com" });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
ADD . .
RUN npm install
CMD node index.js
```

Building image
docker build --no-cache -t user-api:lastest .

creating a container
docker run --name userapi -d -p 80:3000 2d97204ae010

Output
When I go to the web broswer and type localhost:3000 I get "This page isn’t working" response

Comment: I'd expect that Javascript file to produce JSON-format output.  What URL are you calling that returns that PNG file instead?  Can you [edit] the question to include any text-format output or error messages that are relevant to the question?

Comment: The second `docker run -p` number needs to match the `app.listen(port)` value.  You're forwarding host port 3000 to container port 80 but nothing is listening on port 80 inside the container.  (Which is essentially @DavidAlexander's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72512516) as well.)

Comment: how do I make the container listen to port 80 @DavidMaze

Comment: Change `const port=80;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-p 3000:80` should be `-p 80:3000`. The host port number comes first, and the container port number second. See [this section of the `docker run` docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) for more details.

Comment: It did not work for me

Comment: Can you give more detail on what is going wrong? What URL are you entering into the web browser? (Should be `http://localhost`.) What error does it show? If you have [`curl`](https://curl.se/download/curl-7.83.1.zip) installed, you could also try running `curl -v http://localhost` and see what comes out of that. Are there any logs from the container (you can see these using [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/), or by doing your `docker run` command again without `-d`). What about your other container (`website`) - does it work as expected?

Comment: I have checked the logs and everything is working fine but when I try to access the port on my browser I get "The page isn't working" response. The website is not working as expected. it shows the nginx default page